# Escape line breaks in MySQL output

Tags: mysql

I have a a column I want to inspect that contains strings with newlines in them. I want to be able to explicitly see the `\n` and `\r` characters that are in these strings. Is there some way to write my SQL query to tell it to output the strings with the newlines escaped?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    REPLACE(yourcolumn, '\r', '\\r'),
    '\n',
    '\\n'
) FROM yourtable;
```