# REST API - Escaping characters

Tags: rest, escaping, ascii, mysql-real-escape-string

Let's assume I have a notes field with new lines characters in it.
What solution is correct and what is the difference between them?

1

```
{
"notes" : "test test test \n line2"
}
```

2

```
{
"notes" : "test test test \\n line2"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is that supposed to be? JSON? What does `mysql_real_escape_string()` have to do with it? Your question is lacking essential details. There is no "correct solution" when the problem statement is missing.

Comment: This is a response returned from API. I was wondering how to escape characters.

Comment: You are not being thorough in your explanations. Assume I know *nothing* about your application, the APIs you use, the data types they return, the code you wrote, or what you want to escape your data for. You need to explain these things in your question if you hope to get a useful answer.

Comment: Alright, Sorry about my poor explanation. Let's assume, as you said, that you don't know anything about how the API are built but you need to use them to retrieve some content. For instance, you need to retrieve some notes from the API and print them. Either in an HTML page or an iOS application, doesn't matter. Would you expect the API to return the notes as defined in the first example or in the second one?

Comment: So assuming the API returns proper JSON (i.e. the result of running a JSON encoding function over an actual data structure, not the result of string concatenation), then it would still depend on whether I want to see a literal "\n" in my resulting data - or whether I want a line break. "\n" in JSON's way of encoding a newline character.  "\\" is JSON's way of encoding a backslash. Also note that line breaks in text don't cause line breaks on screen for most situations in HTML, so that's another issue right there. Your explanation is still lacking.

Answer (score 0):

In the output below:

```
{
 "notes" : "test test test \n line2"
}
```

a new line character has been escaped using `\n`.

On your UI, you probably want to show

```
test test test 
line2
```

I am assuming that you are retrieving the json from a data store (perhaps MySQL). If yes please see [this answer about escaping newline chars in MYSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326168/escape-line-breaks-in-mysql-output) and [MySQL string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)