# MYSQL: How to make text after newline character position itself in the same column?

Tags: python, mysql

I am presently learning MYSQL using a python approach and also using MYSQL in a bash shell.

I have text that contains  a newline character in a column named **"On_Sale"**.MYSQL does not automatically add the newline character followed by the remainding text  **in the same column named On_Sale**.
The picture below shows my output in a bash shell.

[image: Snapshot]

Below are my python codes:

```
with sql:
    sqlcur=sql.cursor()
    sqlcur.execute("DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS Apple_Juices")
    sqlcur.execute("CREATE TABLE Apple_Juices(No INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Juices VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',Department VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '',On_Sale VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT '')")
    sqlcur.execute("INSERT INTO Apple_Juices (Juices) VALUES('Mango')")
    sqlcur.execute("INSERT INTO Apple_Juices(Juices,on_sale) VALUES('Pineapples dddfgd','pineaple\ncherry')")
    sqlcur.execute("INSERT INTO Apple_Juices(Juices) VALUES('Orange')")
    sqlcur.execute("INSERT INTO Apple_Juices(Juices) VALUES('Grape')")
    sqlcur.execute("INSERT INTO Apple_Juices(Juices) VALUES('Cherry')")
    sqlcur.execute("describe Apple_Juices")
```

**Is it possible to print the text "pineapple" followed by a newline character followed by the text "cherry" in the same column label On_Sale?**

Comment: I remember I had exactly this problem a few years ago. I finally found the post again by someone who found a nice approach. Here you go: https://geert.vanderkelen.org/2010/mysql-client-tool-and-how-to-output-newlines/

Comment: @HelloWorld..very useful link..however this shows an example with a line break in column1 which automatically pushes the remainding text at the begining of the next row (which  column 1 is located)...I tried using the steps for a data with line breaks in other columns but still get the same results..I wonder if there are any other sql modules in python that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape line breaks in MySQL output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326168/escape-line-breaks-in-mysql-output)